# Response 406 in Python request but works in Postman

Tags: python, api, http, request

I need some help in a POST request to retrieve cookies after login. 
The request works in Postman but not in Python request lib.
I'm getting response code 406 and I have tried to copy the headers from Postman but still failed.
Could anyone guide me on this? Hereby attach the screenshots of my settings.
Could it be something to do with the Set-Cookie response header? AFAIK 406 is caused by client unable to accept response.

[image: Postman headers]

[image: Python headers][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to generate Python code out of *Postman* in order to compare them.

In the toolbar under the url, on the right side, you have a `code` link. Press on it and choose `Python - Requests`. Copy this generated snippet to your IDE and check if it works for you (it should work) and then, you can clean it from unnecessary Postman additions.

Comment: Thanks. Looks i lack of a header with capitalized "Cookie". But still i'm getting 403 after that. Hmm

Comment: Yeah it didnt. There were two cookie declared, first declare "cookie" and second declared "Cookie". And from the python result, it seems that the second "Cookie" overwritten the first "cookie". Here's the screenshot: https://imgur.com/2FlFqzZ

Comment: This is not a postman generated request. Postman adds few headers that doesn't appear in your request.

Comment: Yes it is. As you can see in my first photo, the hidden cookie headers starting with "SPC_IA=-1; SPC_SI=zduimx" is shown. I have opened a new py script to run and here's the result screenshot. https://imgur.com/iC0sEPN

Comment: Solved. Removed the wrong cookie added by Postman and voila worked. At the same time, problem with me code should be the wrong body passed. It takes json instead of plain text. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Happy to help :)